# Bash script for restart binary on error

Tags: shell-script

I wrote a small service in Go which must keep running always. But it's full of bugs, which sometimes lead to crash. Nevertheless, I want it to be restarted on any error and log errors to file. I think it could be done by executing it like

`screen -d -m "./my_compiled_binary 2> on_error.sh"`

But I'm not sure, what must be in `on_error.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `> outputfile` redirects the output of the command to a file, `2> errorfile` redirects `stderr`, the error output, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Redirection

What you probably want is a loop, like:

```
while true ; do 
    ./my_compiled_binary 2>> errorlog 
    sleep 1
done
```

That will (unconditionally) restart the program after one second, and redirects error output to file `errorlog` (appending to the file, since `>>` instead of a single `>`).
See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals